# Getting last item in tree hierarchy

Tags: c#, linq

I have a menu that supports multiple levels of hierarchy. I have created a function to get me the last item in the tree and return its id. I need this id so I can hide the move down arrow on a management page.

While this works, I spent 2 days trying to find a LINQ way of doing the same thing. So my questions are:

-Is it possible to do this in a purely LINQ way?
-If so, how?

My model for MenuItem looks like this:

```
public partial class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem()
    {
        this.ChildMenuItems = new HashSet<MenuItem>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MenuItemTypeId { get; set; }
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentMenuItemId { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }

    public virtual MenuItemType MenuItemType { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> ChildMenuItems { get; set; }
    public virtual MenuItem ParentMenuItem { get; set; }
}
```

and my recursive function looks like this:

```
public static int GetLastMenuItemId(List<MenuItem> menuItems)
{
    foreach (MenuItem menuItem in menuItems.OrderBy(mi => mi.Rank))
    {                
        lastId = menuItem.Id;
        if (menuItem.ChildMenuItems.Any())
        {
            GetLastMenuItemId(menuItem.ChildMenuItems.ToList());
        }
    }
    return lastId;
}
```

Additionally, my menu tree currently looks like this:

```
Categories: 8 Parent: n/a
Admin: 1 Parent: n/a
    Manage Menus: 2 Parent: 1
        Manage Menus: 7 Parent: 2
        ------------: 5 Parent: 2
        Menus: 3 Parent: 2
        Menu Item Types: 4 Parent: 2
        Menu Items: 6 Parent: 2
    Manage Categories: 9 Parent: 1
    Manage Clicks: 10 Parent: 1
    Manage Comments: 11 Parent: 1
    Manage Images: 12 Parent: 1
    Manage Ratings: 13 Parent: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a function to your MenuItem class that checks for the current MenuItem's position in the collection of the parent MenuItem's child MenuItems.

```
public List<MenuItem> FlattenedChildNodes {
  get {
    var ret = new List<MenuItem>();

    foreach (var item in ChildMenuItems) {
       ret.Add(item);

       if(item.ChildMenuItems != null) {
          ret.AddRange(item.FlattenedChildNodes);
       }
    }

    return ret;
  }
}  



public bool IsLastChild {
      get {
        if (ParentMenuItem == null) // return false if we have no parent (it's the root node)
           return false;
        else // return true iff we're the last child in the parent's collection of children
           return (ParentMenuItem.FlattenedChildNodes.ToList().IndexOf(this) == (ParentMenuItem.FlattenedChildNodes.ToList().Count - 1));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Would this support being many levels deep where the last item on a level is not necessarily the last item in the tree? I've added the current menu tree structure for clarity.

Comment: I'd think so.  I'm assuming that you don't want a down arrow to appear if a MenuItem is the last child at any level?  In your example, Admin: 1 Parent: n/a, Menu Items: 6 Parent: 2, and Manage Ratings: 13 Parent: 1 would have no down arrow.

Comment: You'd also have to add a root node so that every displayed node has a parent (otherwise there's no way to tell if Admin: 1 Parent: n/a is the last MenuItem in the level 1 collection of MenuItems.

Comment: Unfortunalty, I only want the very bottom item, in the example above, ID 13, to hide the down arrow. I've coded the moving of menu item up and down the tree, i just need to hide the arrow for the one where it cannot go lower.

As for the root node, I am using a different class for the root of the menu (called "Menu") instead of another MenuItem node. This is for other reasons (managing multiple menus) and am not looking to change that.

Comment: I'll look into your suggestion but I am still interested in finding a LINQ statement/query to do the same as my function.